# Convert C# string to C char array

Tags: c#, c

I am sending a `string` from C# to C via sockets:

```
write 5000 100
```

In C, I split the received `string` using spaces.

```
char **params = str_split(buffer, ' ');
```

And then access the 3rd parameter, and convert `100` into C `char`. However, I need to be able to send an `array` of `chars` from C# (1 `byte` each) so that I can use them in C.

For instance, let's say I need to send the following string:

`write 5000 <byte[] { 0x01, 0x20, 0x45 }>`

Of course, the `byte` `array` needs to be transformed into `string` characters in C# that can be sent via `StreamWriter`. `StreamWriter` accepts `array` of `chars` which are 2 bytes each, but I need 1 byte.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why do you need to use StreamWriter?

Comment: i actually dont need to use it..

Comment: If you use Stream (as opposed to StreamWriter), then you can just send bytes. But not characters. I don't know much about C#, so what happens if you use your StreamWriter for characters and Stream for bytes? Or cast each char to byte before writing it to the Stream directly (only works for ASCII).

Comment: Look down below for anwser. I got that from a website and made a little tweak. Is it good?

Comment: heres the problem.. the "write 5000" part is chars, but i guess i want to mix both chars and bytes together. a solution i suppose would be to just use bytes, but that would require changing the way i communicate, ie. first 4 bytes the command, next 4 bytes the int value, and then the byte array

Comment: What's the `c++` tag for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `char` is of 1 byte size. Thus, to accommodate them from C#, you will need to send `byte`.

And it seems like you need ***two*** different inputs for your problem:

**C#**

```
string textFront = "write 5000"; //input 1
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x20, 0x45 }; //input 2
```

And then to send them together, I would rather use `Stream` which allows you to send `byte[]`. Thus, we only need to (1) Change the `textFront` into `byte[]`, (2) concat `textFront` with `bytes`, and lastly (3) send combined variable as `byte[]`.

```
byte[] frontBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textFront); // no (1)

byte[] combined = new byte[frontBytes.Length + bytes.Length];
frontBytes.CopyTo(combined, 0);
bytes.CopyTo(combined, frontBytes.Length); //no (2)

Stream stream = new StreamWriter(); //no (3)
stream.Write(combined, 0, combined.Length);
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, thanks for the CopyTo, was just looking for that also

Comment: @user2914191 great. =) glad that it fits to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, is it what you are looking for?

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your string");
```

and vice versa

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: the answer to my question is not to send chars but to send bytes

Answer (score 0):

The StreamWriter constructor may receive a Encoding parameter. Maybe that's what you want.

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(your_stream, Encoding.ASCII);
sw.Write("something");
```

There is also the BinaryWriter class that can write strings and byte[].

```
var bw = new BinaryWriter(output_stream, Encoding.ASCII);
bw.Write("something");
bw.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x20, 0x45 });
```